# Pygame code lags out with a flickering mouse

Tags: python, pygame, python-3.6

So I'm trying to create a button that will simply set the background images(by blitting one over the other). But, I think this code should work:

```
place = True
action = None
def startup(action):
    while place == True:
    gameDisplay.blit(imgstr, (0, 0))
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    if 500+140 > mouse[0] > 500 and 140+150 > mouse[1] > 140:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, black, (500,140,150,150))
        pygame.mouse.set_cursor(*pygame.cursors.tri_left)
        if click[0] == 1 and action != None:
            if action == "play":
                game_loop()
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, white, (500,140,150,150))
        pygame.mouse.set_cursor(*pygame.cursors.arrow)
def game_loop():
    while place == True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_RCTRL:
                    pygame.quit()
                    quit()
        gameDisplay.blit(imgm, (0, 0))

        pygame.display.update()
startup("play")
```

But pygame just launches with a black screen, and the mouse flickers, until Windows stops it because it isn't responding.

Comment: Your indention is incorrect and will resolve in an `IndentionError`. Make sure the code you post here matches your actual code. Also, it's not responding because your not calling any [event functions](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/pygame/5110/event-handling/18049/state-checking#t=201705171154322622145) (The third bullet point). The reason for the black screen is that you don't update display at `startup`.

Comment: @TedKleinBergman I've added a for event in pygame.event.get() loop in between the first if statement and the while loop in the startup() statement, and also added the pygame.display.update() to startup(), however, now it will only draw the rectangle once in white, is this an indentation error, and if it is how do I fix it? I know it may seem like I'm being vague but, my command prompt won't run the code, so I have absolutely no error messages to help.

Comment: If you've made changes in your code, then edit your question with the new code. If your code contains an `IndentationError`, then it cannot be run at all. In the code you've provided in your question there's no indentation after the line `while place == True:`, which should crash your program immediately. I would recommend following a beginners tutorial on Python and learn more about debugging and errors before you start programming graphical applications. Graphical application can require much debugging and without a good understanding it could become very tough and annoying.

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully solved the problem with the following code, if anyone was wondering:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode([852,441])

pygame.display.set_caption("test")

keep_going = True
mousedown = True

background_image = pygame.image.load("start.jpg")

main_img = pygame.image.load("chromos.png")

colorkey = background_image.get_at((0,0))
background_image.set_colorkey(colorkey)
black = (0,0,0)
red = (255,0,0)

picx = 0
picy = 0

main_picx = 0
main_picy = 0

screen.fill(red)

while keep_going:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            keep_going = False
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if pygame.mouse.get_pos() > (500, 500) and pygame.mouse.get_pos() < (700, 700):
                picx = 5000
                picy = 5000
                mousedown = False
        print(event)
    if mousedown:
        screen.blit(background_image, (picx,picy))
    else:
        screen.blit(main_img, (main_picx, main_picy))
    pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
quit()
```